# a C program to test MIPS processor with my FPGA board

Tags: c, mips, cross-compiling, fpga

I want to write a simple c program that reads from a memory address (Nexus 3 switches) to a variable. Then, writes this variable to the address of the LEDs
under the gcc MIPS cross compiler

I want any tutorial or links to do that ??
 I searched a lot but still confused so please help me ??

Comment: Why do you tag it with FPGA? And for gods sake have you heard of something called "search engine" ?

Comment: because  I want to test MIPS processor on FPGA board and have you heard about someone is vain and not being gentle???

Comment: Well, this is a proper question but it has nothing to do with FPGA. I understand your position, but you are not cross compiling FPGA code, you are creating your code on a PC and downloading it on MIPS. It is impossible for people to answer your question without knowing how your systme is built. Reading switches and lighting up LEDs should be a simple IO access or writing ot a specific memory location, check out your system build and see where those IOs are mapped.

Comment: I'm just afew month working with hardware so sorry if my questions not very clear i havenot got that  check out your system build and see where those IOs are mapped. because i have VHDL code of mips and i need to test that code how can i test my instructions is work correctly

Comment: Your MIPS cocde does not help with the memory mapping. This is  SW setting of your system. You must ask your professor or the person who built the system for giving the address map of the devices of the Nexus board in order to be ablel to use them WE can't help you with that.